# Adjusting the colour/contrast/gamma etc of the video source

Tags: image, television, hdmi, adjustment

I would like to know whether a Google TV device could be used as a 'man in the middle' and make manual adjustments to the colour and gamma of the input source from HDMI in, before output to the TV?

There are several apps already for phones/tablets which allow for these adjustments but I'm unsure what (if any) control over the video signal can be acheived with a GTV device.

Any insight into the feesibility of such an application would be most appreciated.